# Detect if USB is Inserted through Application

Tags: windows, usb

I want to create an application or modify USB in a way so that, upon insertion into any PC, I can get the information that PC was inserted.

eg. upon insertion, I can read PC name and make an API call with this as post data so I'm able to know that my USB was inserted in some PC. But this should happen right away as USB is read by the machine, so even if the user formats it thereafter, it should not matter.

If it was earlier windows, I could write autorun and that would work. But I want this detection mechanism for Windows 7 and above.

I have done some research on the topic but could not find any reliable content. Some articles were related to USB based hacking attacks by changing wiring (USB hardware, to harm the computer) or something like that. But I totally don't want to do that. Just the detection, that USB was used.

Comment: As you say autorun was killed off for USB devices for security reasons, you simply cannot automatically execute a program from such devices (thankfully).

Comment: @AlexK. I understand that. But is there a way to probably make a curl call? and that's it...Although if that be possible, many other things possibilities open up.

Comment: By program, it is done with **WM_DEVICECHANGE** ([Detecting Media Insertion or Removal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devio/detecting-media-insertion-or-removal))

Comment: No, no way, this ability was removed for a reason - if a method did emerge it would be considered a vulnerability & fixed.